# Getting back data from DescribeSecurityGroupsRequest

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am trying to get a list of all the security groups within the AWS region, although I have no idea how I can output the actual Security Group IDs, Name etc.

```
//Switch region to eu-west-1
ec2Client = new AmazonEC2Client(RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("eu-west-1"));

//Describe all the security groups
var securityGroup = new DescribeSecurityGroupsRequest();
Console.WriteLine(securityGroup.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DescribeSecurityGroupsRequest` class is simply the request object. So you fill it with your input requirements (in your case, most likely there won't be any).

Then you need to call `DescribeSecurityGroups()' on your client:

```
var client = new AmazonEC2Client(RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("eu-west-1"));
var request = new DescribeSecurityGroupsRequest();
var response = client.DescribeSecurityGroups(request);
```

The `response` object will contain your security group information.